Why does the keyword "this" work like this in these examples
I was looking for examples of how "this" works and found this example:
function foo() {
  return {
      x: 20,
      bar: () => {
          console.log(this.x);
      },
      baz: function () {
          console.log(this.x);
      }
  };
}


const obj2 = foo.call({ x: 30 });

let y = obj2.bar; 
let z = obj2.baz; 
y(); // Output: 30
z(); // Output: undefined

I roughly understand why it gives such a result, but then I've tried to modify this example and and set the value to this.x inside the function and remove .call().
function foo() {
  this.x = 50;
  return {
      x: 20,
      bar: () => {
          console.log(this.x);
      },
      baz: function () {
          console.log(this.x);
      }
  };
}


const obj2 = foo();

let y = obj2.bar; 
let z = obj2.baz; 
y(); // Output: 50
z(); // Output: 50

Can someone explain why it works this way?

A question for a question: what calling foo from the top-level and setting this does, what this refers to?

Your confusion seems to stem from the fact that you didn't use strict mode. Had you used it, it'd be a lot clearer. Right now you're mixing way more than needed into the concept. In sloppy mode this = window when it's undefined. And it's implicitly undefined with your modification. In strict mode you'd just get an error immediately when you try to implicitly meddle with the global object. Just always use strict mode and you'd avoid similar problems in the future.

Additional existing question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34361379/are-arrow-functions-and-functions-equivalent-interchangeable

"I found this example" - where did you find it and what was the explanation that came with it?
